# How to let Laravel pivot table use only created_at?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

When dealing with belongsToMany relation, you use a pivot table to record the relation.

For many pivot tables, the relations are just created and then deleted. They won't have their own property, so you never update them.

I know I can do this to auto-set both updated_at and created_at.

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function bars() {
        $this->belongsToMany(Bar::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

But how to use only created_at? I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take another approach:

- Skip the `withTimestamps()` method (to avoid adding both `created_at` and `updated_at` columns).
- Add a custom pivot column: `created_at`.

So your code:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function bars() {
        $this->belongsToMany(Bar::class)->withPivot('created_at');
    }  //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Now, with this approach you will need to set the value of `created_at` manually when creating records:

```
$foo = Foo::find(1);
$foo->bars()->attach($someId, ['created_at' => now()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')]);
//                             or whatever you use as date   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, this column won't be casted as a `Date` by default -as opposed to what Laravel do with timestamp columns- so this:

```
$foo->bars()->first()->pivot->created_at
```

won't be an instance of [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). If you want it though, [you could create a custom Pivot model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models), then specify [the column to cast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) and update your relationship to use the custom Pivot model:

Pivot model `FooBar.php`

```
class FooBar extends Pivot // <--
{
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:d-m-Y H:i:s',
    ];
}
```

Then in your `Foo.php` class:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function bars() {
        $this->belongsToMany(Bar::class)->using(FooBar::class)->withPivot('created_at');
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and realized if you are using timestamps in a pivot table, Laravel thinks you are using both `created_at` and `updated_at`. A workaround is to override the `addTimestampsToPivot` method by adding these methods to the model:

```php
protected function addTimestampsToPivot(array $attributes)
{
    if ($this->pivotCreatedAt()) {
        $attributes[$this->pivotCreatedAt()] = $this->freshTimestamp();
    }

    return $attributes;
}

public function pivotCreatedAt()
{
    return 'created_at';
}
```